# how to pause css animation on hover using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

How do we pause CSS animation on its state when user hovers the element.

**CSS**

```
.container {
  height: 160px; width: 450px; background: gray; overflow: hidden;
}
.marquee {
  height: 140px; width: 400px; margin: 10px; background: red; position: relative; animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes marquee {
   0% {left: 100%;}
   100% {left: -100%;}
}

.marquee:hover {
  /* pause animation. this works but with compatibility issues 
     animation-play-state is still in W3C working draft
  */
  animation-play-state: paused; 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="marquee"></div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).raedy(function() {
   $(.marquee).hover { //mouseenter() & mouseleave()
      // puase animation
   }
});
```

my jsfiddle link here https://jsfiddle.net/gamss0wa/6/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can pause animation using css

```
.marquee:hover 
{
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
    -o-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

Comment: nice thanks. i didn't know css animation-play-state exists.

Comment: i'm just scared to use your solution for compatibility issue.

Comment: its same thing css animation will work on browser then animation-play-state will work otherwise not

Comment: based on this info animation-play-state is not yet standardized  refer here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation-play-statehttps://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation-play-state